# graphlab create sframe combine two column

Tags: python, pandas, graphlab

I have two columns with strings. let's say col1 and col2
now how can we combine the content of col1 and col2  into col3 with graphlab SFrame?

```
col1 col2
23    33
42    11
........
```

into

```
col3
23,33
42,11
....
```

unstack will only give sarray or dict, i only one a bag of words

tried

```
user_info['X5']=user_info['X3'].apply(lambda x:x+','+user_info['X4'].apply(lambda y:y))
```

doesnt seem to be right

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas:

```
In [271]: df
Out[271]: 
   col1  col2
0    23    33
1    42    11

In [272]: df['col3'] = (df['col1'].map(str) + ',' + df['col2'].map(str))

In [273]: df
Out[273]: 
   col1  col2   col3
0    23    33  23,33
1    42    11  42,11
```

Using graphlab:

```
In [17]: sf
Out[17]: 
Columns:
    col1    int
    col2    int

Rows: 2

Data:
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|  23  |  33  |
|  42  |  11  |
+------+------+
[2 rows x 2 columns]

In [18]: sf['col3'] = sf['col1'].apply(str) + ',' + sf['col2'].apply(str)

In [19]: sf
Out[19]: 
Columns:
    col1    int
    col2    int
    col3    str

Rows: 2

Data:
+------+------+-------+
| col1 | col2 |  col3 |
+------+------+-------+
|  23  |  33  | 23,33 |
|  42  |  11  | 42,11 |
+------+------+-------+
[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: yes but how can we do it in graphlab create though?

Comment: i see, tested work. why apply(str)?  can it be apply( int)?

Comment: @ikel `','` is a `string`. You cannot concatenate a `string` with an object of type `int`.